# Why won't my notebook display figure after reading in from another notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, papermill

I'm aware thet plots and notebooks can have some interesting behaviour when used together. This must be a fairly standard thing to encounter for anyone following the `papermill` usage guide.

Here is the documentation I'm following to the letter:

https://github.com/nteract/papermill

If you scroll down 2/3 of the way there is a brief section on **Displaying Plots and Images Saved by Other Notebooks**.

In my case, the figure displays fine in the original notebook, but in the destination notebook the figure is read but not displayed, I simply get:

```
In [4]: out.display_output('matplotlib_hist')
        <Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>
```

Comment: Try using `%matplotlib inline` at the start of the destination notebook.

Comment: Ty. (You actually need it in the _source_ nb as the _dest_ is simply generated when the source is run!)